# Angular Routing - how to using wild card route correctly, for nested route like xxx/xxx?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

How to using wild card route correctly, for nested route like xxx/xxx?

I want to redirect host:port/XXX/XXX to page-not-found, however, my wild card route only accept routing host:port/XXX, not host:port/XXX/XXX.

This is my route configured at app.module.ts:

```
  const routes: Routes = [     
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];
```

---

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

---

- For the url 'host:port/main', I would get the main page.
- For the url 'host:port/XXXX', I would get the page-not-found page.
- However, for the url 'host:port/XXXX/XXXX', I would get an empty page.

  - It only download index.html (and named by 'XXXX') successfully, no style.css, no assets, no main.js.
  - Both using ng service and build as production have the same issue.

---

My files: (using Angular 10.0.10)

```
app
--- page-not-found/page-not-found.component.ts
--- main/maincomponent.ts
--- app.component.ts
--- app.module.ts
assets
environment
index.html
main.ts
style.css
… (other files auto generated by angular cli)
```

---

Thank you.

Comment: try `{ path: '**', redirectTo: PageNotFoundComponent }`

Comment: `""` is your default route, `"**"` should be your 404 route

Comment: @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX Thank you for your advice, however, add component after 'redirctTo' would cause the error: `Type 'typeof PageNotFoundComponent' is not assignable to type 'string'` . I've also tried this: `{
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',    
    redirectTo: '**'
  }`;  the behavior of `host:port/XXXX/XXXX` is the same

Comment: @MikeS. Thank you! Yap, my default route is 404. I've tried: `{ path: 'page-not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent }, { path: '**', redirectTo: 'page-not-found' }` And the behavior of `host:port/XXXX/XXXX` is the same.